# How to insert EntityFramework with circular references withouth Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

> Error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.CompanyDtoes'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.CompanyDtoes'. The
>   duplicate key value is (b20a140d-440b-4a41-b2c3-6763fa752246). The
>   statement has been terminated.

PersonDto

```
public class PersonDto : PartnerDto, IPartner
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public string BirthPlace { get; set; }
    public string MothersName { get; set; }
    public string TaxId { get; set; }
    public List<CompanyDto> OwnedCompanies { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Partner címe(i)
    /// </summary>
    public List<PersonAddressDto> Addresses { get; set; }

    public PersonDto()
    {
        OwnedCompanies = new List<CompanyDto>();
        Addresses = new List<PersonAddressDto>();
    }
}
```

CompanyDto

```
public class CompanyDto : PartnerDto, IPartner
{
    public string TaxNumber { get; set; }
    public int CompanyValue { get; set; }
    public List<PersonDto> Owners { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Partner címe(i)
    /// </summary>
    public List<CompanyAddressDto> Addresses { get; set; }

    public CompanyDto()
    {
        Owners = new List<PersonDto>();
        Addresses = new List<CompanyAddressDto>();
    }
}
```

My DBContext:

```
public class PartnerDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<PersonDto> Persons { get; set; }

    public DbSet<CompanyDto> Companies { get; set; }

    public DbSet<AddressDto> Addresses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PersonDto>()
            .HasKey(k => k.PartnerId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyDto>()
            .HasKey(k => k.PartnerId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<AddressDto>()
            .HasKey(k => k.ID);
    }
}
```

I try to insert a new person, that contains some references for already exists companies:

```
public bool InsertPerson(PersonDto personToInsert)
{
    try
    {
        using (var db = new PartnerDBContext())
        {
            db.Persons.Add(personToInsert);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

My problem that, I can't insert it, cos it writes Violation of primary key for CompanyDto. I know it's already exists and I don't want to add a new one, but how should I add it? I use it in a WCF service, that called from UWP. Unfortunately can't use DataAnnonations using from UWP (it's a bug), so I use ModelBuilder...

Answer (score 0):

```
    public bool InsertPerson(PersonDto personToInsert)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new PartnerDBContext())
            {
                var companies = personToInsert.OwnedCompanies;

                personToInsert.OwnedCompanies = new List<CompanyDto>();

                foreach (var company in companies)
                {
                    var companyInDb = db.Companies.Find(company.PartnerId);
                    personToInsert.OwnedCompanies.Add(companyInDb);
                }

                db.Persons.Add(personToInsert);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I found that solution if I get the companies from the db it saves everything as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you add the person entity to the context, it also adds the related entities and marks them as `Added` (i.e. new). The `SaveChanges()` in turn tries to insert them in the database and you get the duplicate PK exception.

The solution you posted works, but involves unnecessary database trips for  retrieving the related objects. Since you know they are existing, you can avoid that by simply attaching them to the context in advance, which will mark them as `Unchanged` (i.e. existing). Then `SaveChanges` will insert only the person record and the links.

```
using (var db = new PartnerDBContext())
{
    foreach (var company in personToInsert.OwnedCompanies)
        db.Companies.Attach(company);
    db.Persons.Add(personToInsert);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Alternatively you can mark them as `Unchanged` after adding the person to the context:

```
using (var db = new PartnerDBContext())
{
    db.Persons.Add(personToInsert);
    foreach (var company in personToInsert.OwnedCompanies)
        db.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

In my test (latest EF6.1.3, short lived new `DbContext` as in the posted sample) both approaches work.

Comment: I tried this before, but it also wrote me the same error  when I tried to attach. :o ...

Comment: I've tested it before posting, and It works in my environment (latest EF6.1.3 if that matters).

Comment: First solution writes me: Attaching an entity of type 'andocdemo.Model.Dto.Partner.CompanyDto' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' o...

Comment: The second one writes me: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.CompanyDtoes'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.CompanyDtoes'. The duplicate key value is (70fb08e5-8c4a-4dad-8cce-d8a378226921).
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: I believe you have tested, but than what can be the problem in my solution?

Comment: Hmm, the only logical reason this code to fail and your current solution to work is if you have companies with duplicate `PartnerId` inside `personToInsert.Compaines` list.

Comment: If you compare  `personToInsert.OwnedCompanies.Select(c => c.PartnerId).Distinct().Count()` with `personToInsert.OwnedCompanies.Count`, are they the different?

Comment: They have same count. I use this DBContext in a WCF project, that is called from an UWP project... It may can causes some problems...